# Spring Boot and Thymeleaf are returning a 400 error on field errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.1 and Thymeleaf for a simple registration app so a user can create and save a `Member` model to the database. I'm using the `javax.validation` framework to ensure fields are not empty and it works fine when the model is valid, but an invalid model with missing fields kicks me out with a 400 error code to my default `error.html` page, instead of taking the user back to the registration form where I can display field-level errors (e.g., "Username is required").

The model is simple and looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="member")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
   
    // ... getters and setters
```

The controller looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public ModelAndView registerMember(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                       @ModelAttribute @Valid Member member, ModelMap model, BindingResult result){
   log.info("Attempting to register a user");

   // some other error checking not related to javax.validation ...

   memberService.save(member);

   return new ModelAndView("/success", model);
}
```

Finally, the (simplified) HTML/Thymeleaf form looks like this (`register.html`):

```
       <form th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${member}" method="post">

             <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="username" th:field="*{username}">

             <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password"  id="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}">

             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login">
        </form>
```

On form submit with a value for `username` and `password` everything works, but if I omit either of those, like the `username` I get the following `WARN` log statement:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 4 errors
Field error in object 'member' on field 'username': rejected value []; codes [NotEmpty.member.username,NotEmpty.username,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [member.username,username]; arguments []; default message [username]]; default message [must not be empty]
```

But then the server returns a 400 error and renders the `error.html` page instead of returning to the form, and equally important is my `registerMember()` method in the controller isn't called at all. It by passes my logic entirely so I can't even manually inspect the errors using `BindingResult`.

If I omit the `@Valid` annotation on my model like `@ModelAttribute Member member` then my method is invoked but none of the `javax.validation` is used and the `BindingResult.getErrorCount()` is `0`, thus defeating the entire point of using it (I'd have to validate myself manually).

Any idea how I can let `@Valid` do its job *and* return back to the `/register` endpoint to display the field-level errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this problem by following ways.

1. You need to change the method signature from

public ModelAndView registerMember(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute @Valid Member member, ModelMap model, BindingResult result)

to this

```
public ModelAndView registerMember(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute @Valid Member member, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
```

Because binding result should be immediate to @Valid object.

After this you can errors and send it desired form as below

```
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
     return "register";
}
```

2. You can controller advice for handling exceptions

@RestControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc

public class ExceptionAdvice {

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public Response handleInvaldException (MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, Response response) {    
      Map < String, String > errors = new HashMap < > ();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((err) - > {
        String fieldName = ((FieldError) err).getField();
        String errorMessage = err.getDefaultMessage();
        errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
    });
    response.setData(errors);
   retr
}
```

}

Comment: Your suggestion to reposition the `BindingResult` parameter next to the `Member` fixed the problem and now it drops into my logic, plus reports the errors. Thanks! This combined with @3asyPe suggestion for front-end form validation using `required` completed the client and server side checks.

Comment: hi hello @vishal-pawar is it mentioned in the documentation that valid annotation must followed by BindingResult? can you provide the link

Answer (score 1):

In real applications, form validation occurs on the front-end side. I highly recommend you to read about default html and js form validation. For example, `@NotNull` validation is just `required` attribute at your html tag. This attribute will not allow you to submit the form while the field is empty. More complex validation can be performed using simple JS or jQuery.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="username" th:field="*{username}" required>
```

On the back-end side, annotations such as @NotNull are used for rechecking that you are not saving incorrect data to your db. But it is unnatural to use these annotations as the only check.

Comment: Although I accepted the other answer because it dealt with the `@Valid` issue, your suggestion to also add the browser-side `required` validation is very helpful and will make the form more user friendly. Thanks!